# How do I solve for distance in the $x$ when only given the radiant velocity and the angle above the horizontal?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

I recently had a physics test in AP physics one algebra based that my entire class failed. It was full of questions like this:
A projectile is launched from a level surface toward a cliff. At launch, the projectile has a velocity of 233.41 m/s at an angle 24.6° above the horizontal. Air resistance is negligible.

Calculate the horizontal distance that the projectile travels before it hits the ground.

How do you solve a question like this?

Comment: *How do you solve a question like this?* Can you determine the functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know, this is all the information given to us in these types of questions

Comment: If the entire class really did fail there may be an issue with the teaching. Is the teacher teaching the things that are on the test? Is this the standardized AP test or is it a test prepared by the teacher that's meant to be on things they specifically discussed in class?

Comment: The functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ can be determined from the data given, plus the acceleration due to gravity, $g$, which near the surface of the Earth is just a constant.

Comment: Do you understand in equations how a dropped object falls under gravity?

Comment: This problem is simply impossible to answer.  Without knowing the height and distance of the cliff, and whether the gun is at the top or the bottom of the cliff, no meaningful analysis is possible.

Answer (score 0):

First, we should look at what is going on in this problem conceptually. The object is being launched at some angle (think about someone throwing a ball). It falls over the edge of the cliff. If you drop a ball (no initial velocity), the ball falls straight down. However, you know that if you throw a ball, it will traverse some distance horizontally as well (i.e. if you throw it at an angle it might travel in front of you). Thus, we can expect the object here to have some motion vertically and horizontally.

Now, we also have a key piece of information. The object is falling due to gravity. We can split the trajectory of this ball into two problems: 1) the ball falls directly downwards and 2) the ball travels to the right (if we picture the cliff falls off on the right side). This is the initial velocity and gravity working together to move the ball/projectile.

Now, we know that once the ball travels as far down as it can, it will stop moving. **Thus, the the amount the ball can traverse the horizontal plane (the amount it moves to the right in our model) is limited by how far it can travel in the time it takes the ball to hit the ground**. Now, you should see we have gathered all of the necessary pieces. You can write an equation for $y(t)$, set $y(t_{\text{final}}) = 0$ (you want the ball to hit the ground), solve for $t$, then plug that into your equation for $x(t)$ to find $x(t_{\text{final}})$.

You need to know the initial value of $y_0$ (height of cliff) to get a numerical result, or you can leave your answer in terms of $y_0$.

I would encourage you to not focus on the fact that your entire class failed. These are pretty standard AP physics questions, and you would benefit from mastering them. :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering, it means a lot! Unfortunately, the questions that were like that only had the information I stated, no height, just the radiant velocity and angle launched at.

Comment: @Relativisticcumber sorry for the late reply. Turns out my teacher wanted us to solve it by doing 233.41cos(24.6) to get velocity in the x, and then solving from there. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think that is the first step, but I do think you need to do the rest of the method above to get the final answer. I do believe that, as a user above said, you cannot get a numerical answer without the height of the cliff, so I would be interested to see your solution. You can answer via q&a style on this site if you are interested in doing so. @Ligig